# White Page After Installing PHP NGINX

Tags: nginx, php

I've looked into around 25 different tutorials and threads on this issue and how installation **should** go, yet I am still getting this error.

Whenever I visit a PHP page after installing php5-fpm to sit alongside NGINX, it renders a white page with no error messages, **also note** that in /var/log/NGINX, the log is empty.

My virtual host's config looks like this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

And my www.conf is using the following parameters besides the defaults:

```
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock

listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660

user = www-data
group = www-data
```

Any help appreciated! I've also tried using the TCP port instead of the socket, and I already checked the location of the "fastcgi_params" file and it's where it should be.

Comment: the white page often indicates that nginx is working and php-fpm is failing.  otherwise you'd get a 500 or timeout error from the server.  Is your PHP broken ?  try just loading a simple <?php php_info() file

Comment: @DavidChan I think PHP is broken since I took a simple .html page I had and changed it to .php and it just loaded a blank page as well.

Comment: Just to be sure, you have restarted php-fpm by running: service php5-fpm restart ?

Comment: @nullReference Yessir!

Comment: try running executing php from command line to make sure its installed properly...  check the PHP log

Comment: Check you error logs (nginx + php-fpm).

Comment: Well I just reinstalled Ubuntu and tried everything again from scratch, worked without much tinkering at all *shrugs*

Answer (score 3):

Location in my config:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

I had the same issue, until I added this: `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;`

Comment: I got another error after using this which basically said that it wasn't privileged enough to get the file, so I ran NGINX as a sudo user and it loads a white page again, however if I load a file with actual PHP scripts in it it'll just timeout eventually.

Comment: You changed cgi.fix_pathinfo in /etc/php5/fpm/php.in to zero?

Comment: Oups.. now I saw that fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully these will help. They are my current configuration settings that I am running on my development server for nginx/php-fpm. If this does not help you might try posting something on serverfault:

www.conf

```
[www]

user = www-data
group = www-data

listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock

listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3

chdir = /
```

php-fpm.conf

```
[global]
pid = /var/run/php5-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log
include=/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
```

virtual host config

```
server {

    listen 80;

    root /sites/jason/site.com/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name jason.site.com;

    # Catch all
    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$
    {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /sites/jason/jason.site.com$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SITE_URL jason.site.com;
        fastcgi_param SITE_DIR /sites/jason/jason.site.com;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

And always remember to restart nginx and php-fpm after making changes to the files:

```
service nginx restart
service php5-fpm restart
```

Comment: Still the same after comparing our configs and changing what little difference there is between our configs :/